# How to build a parser for syntactic analysis of regular expressions?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, parsers

Is it possible to build a parsing algorithm that build a parse tree using a top-down method that simulate a derivation process for regular expressions, like we do for type 2 languages?

**My guess**

Given a regular expression *r*, build its FSA, then obtain the grammar that generate *r* in order to build a parse tree

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. A regular expression is not a grammar (and there is no obvious unique homomorphism between regular expressions and regular grammars), so I'm not sure what you expect to be the parse tree. I suppose you could try recursively mapping substrings to subpatterns in the regular expression, but in many cases there are multiple possible mappings.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible and you are on the right track.  You will need to make sure your grammar is %100 correct and probably LL(1), from there you can choose one of many algorithm examples that are out there or write your own.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser

Word of warning: The tricky part won't be the implementation but getting your grammar right.